AWS Glue 3.0: Partition Count changing by itself even after repartition
I have a job running on AWS Glue 3.0 with G.8x worker. I am using 100 workers configuration.
In recent runs, count() was causing OOM and I figured out repartitioning might help.
I read we have to keep the partition count = data set size /128 MB
I decided to go with 32 Partitions, as each worker has 32 vCPUs.
I got the job to pass. But I am not seeing any difference even if I set the repartition count to 32 or 3200.
My assumption - 3200 was a good number because

Each executor has 32 vCPUs
Number of partitions is good if it's a multiple of number of cores

My first question: Is this repartitioning strategy correct, my data set is of size 3GB approx.
Main question: After the repartitioning there are series of joins that happen and then if I check the df.rdd.getNumPartitions(), I can see the partition count to be some random number that what I set initially.
For one run, even though I set it to 320, the number of partitions after the join was 6123.
I am finding it difficult to understand the reason behind this behavior.
Error: An error occurred while calling o270.count.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job 21 cancelled because SparkContext was shut down

.count() does collect the results on the driver node, which is causing your OOM issue.
You have a Dataset of only 3GB, you don't need Spark to process that.
To your question of repartitioning:
If you run wide transformations that require shuffle between nodes, Spark repartitions the data again to run on the executors. You can change this by setting sparkContext.setConf("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "3200")

I need spark as this was just a sample dataset that I am processing, we are expecting more data size in future. Also for my first question, can you please tell me if my repartitioning strategy is ok?

2-4 partitions per core are pretty reasonable, as long as the data is not too big. You can also go with 1, just test it out. It always depends on the data, if it is skewed then you might need less or more partitions.

count should not cause OOM, it collects only 1 number on driver node and not whole dataset!

@Grish Then what could we the reason for OOM when count() was triggered?

@VijethKashyap do you get OOM on driver or executor?

I just get this error. An error occurred while calling o270.count. : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job 21 cancelled because SparkContext was shut down. How do I check it?

There are metrics and there should be more logs as well.

I see it happened during a join, so I suspect it's the executor

@Grish Yes, it is in Executor

@Grish You are right, count indirectly triggered the join transformation in the lineage, where it caused OOM on executor
